# Best way to read and write webp format images in java

Tags: java, webp

The normal Imageio Library says it cannot read the Webp format images. Are there any simple methods to read and webp images in java?

Answer (score 4):

Found this library today: [webp-imageio](https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio). Haven't tried it out yet, but it looks like it'll do encoding using ImageIO.

Comment: Yep, i found it recently as well, and i'm currently trying it out. Thanks! :)

Comment: It seems it calls native code from java (it needs .so or .dll): it is not a standalone solution for java. :(

Comment: Is that the reason, why its not available in maven central repo ?

Comment: Is there any library for decoding animated WebP ?

Answer (score 1):

[sprd-webp](https://github.com/spreadshirt/sprd-webp) is another java JNI library based on [webp-imageio](https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio). It is a wrapper around googles libwebp and not a real java implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[Java VP8 Decoder](http://sourceforge.net/p/javavp8decoder/code/ci/master/tree/src/net/sf/javavp8decoder/imageio/) is a GPL3 library currently in beta that can read webp image format. It seems there is no encoding facility at the moment.

A possible alternative would be using [VLCJ](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/index.html), a Java bindings library for VLC (webp support should be available out-of-box in lastest versions afaik).

A third library is [jvp8](http://jvp8.codeplex.com/), a dual-licensed commercial/GPL native wrapper which allows to  use the VP8 video codec.

Comment: These are both solutions that allow webp decoding, but i need an encoding solution in java...

Comment: aren't vlc trancoding capabilities available in vlcj? it seems they are: http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/faq.html

Comment: yep, but i'm still not sure how i use this to convert an image to webp format... ?

Comment: had you time to try with jvp8?