# Android - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat.WEBP

Tags: android, performance, encoding, email-attachments, webp

I'm trying to use a very simple piece of code that has been supported since API 1.

```
if (bitmap != null) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, IMAGE_QUALITY, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    result = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

somehow,

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, IMAGE_QUALITY, byteArrayOutputStream);
```

gives me that weird error: `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat.WEBP` and this only happens on my moto razr 2.3

i can't find anything on the internet about this. what's going on? (i get that, clearly, motorola's stock android didn't think to include it, but how would i fix this?) any hints?

all i want to do is to compress take a snapshot of the screen (or view), and attach it IN A USER FRIENDLY WAY in `String` form (this same device also doesn't do file attachments correctly either) to the body of an email intent, and pass that off to whoever can send emails.

trying to compress to .jpeg, then converting it to base64 encoded string, and then attaching to email in the body takes forever, and is not very user-responsive. this can't happen.

any help?

Answer (score 3):

android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat.WEBP only works for api level 14 or above.

Try some WebP libraries.
[WebP library for java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861601/webp-library-for-java)

Comment: OH. i see it now. sorry, i misread the docs. Bitmap.CompressionFormat has been there since api level 1. i accidentally read that as the api level for WEBP also. thanks